# Data Type = EmailAddress

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, validation

What types of validations occur within Salesforce Marketing Cloud on a data extension that has a column of data type  = EmailAddress ?

We are sending data (upserting) into a data extension using an API.  In most cases, the data flows in fine, but there is an occasional error returned and the message indicates an "invalid email address".  This is puzzling as we already scrub the email addresses before sending via API.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can validate emails in Marketing Cloud first using [/address/v1/validateEmail](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/validateEmail.htm). Check the syntax of the email address using the API above. You'll also want to see how your data extension is set up. If you're using `EmailAddress` as the primary key it could be duplicate values being used and causing the error.

Also, see this about the [EmailAddress data type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_data_extension_data_types.htm&type=5):

> - An email address
> - Up to 254 characters
> - A field of this type must exist in order for you to send an email to a data extension The system checks the syntax of email address and provides an error when that syntax is incorrect. The system does not verify that the value in this field is a valid email address when importing data, whether it actually receives an email message when included as part of a send.
>
> The system checks the syntax of email address and provides an error
>   when that syntax is incorrect. The system does not verify that the
>   value in this field is a valid email address when importing data,
>   whether it actually receives an email message when included as part of
>   a send.

Lastly, [List Detective](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000335444&type=1&mode=1) also scrubs at send time for data extensions so you may also see discrepancy in numbers because of this SFMC proprietary database.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  We aren't using EmailAddress as primary key.  I wonder if the /address/v1/validateEmail API is being used within SFMC under-the-covers to validate what we are sending in?  If yes, then it may explain what i am seeing, if i understand correctly what i just read about a "known issue" with one of the validators sending an Invalid Response to a valid email address.

Comment: If you're referring to this: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gYdQAI, it says it was fixed in the January 2017 release

Comment: I added some more clarification on the EmailAddress data type. Please also check that the values are not more than 254 characters.

Comment: The restrictions on data type (as shown in your answer) is likely where OP is running into issues. List detective and the API validation endpoint shouldn't really affect the import aspect - that is more related to List Detective. The 'syntax' validation is the only one that might be helpful, but I would note that I have found times that this has given different results than the UI - so it is not an exact match.

Comment: What do they mean by "An email address"? I can't find anywhere defining this.

Comment: @JonMitchell It checks the syntax of the email address. See updated quote above.